# How do I map volume outside C:\Users to container on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, mount

I'm doing server side development and my workspace is located in D: because I'm not a fan of storing data on C: but just can't find a way to map d:\Workspace to /home/workspace

I've tried creating a symblink from C:\Users\username to D:\Workspace by:

1. map C:\Users\username\Workspace to /home/workspace
2. Stop container
3. rename C:\Users\username\Workspace
4. Create symlink named Workspace to D:\Workspace
5. Start container

At first Docker worked fine during that session until I restart Boot2Docker, then start the container I'd get "C:\Users\username\Workspace file exists".

I think this is one Docker's issue but anyways I want to map outside C:\Users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Share workspace between host and Boot2Docker virtual machine

  `$ boot2docker down
  $ cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
  $ VBoxManage sharedfolder add boot2docker-vm --name mydata --hostpath "D:\Workspace"
  $ boot2docker up`
- Mount shared folder

  `$ boot2docker ssh 'sudo mkdir -p /data'
  $ boot2docker ssh 'sudo mount -t vboxsf -o "defaults,uid=33,gid=33,rw" mydata /data'`
- Create data-only container. Docker best practices [always](https://medium.com/@ramangupta/why-docker-data-containers-are-good-589b3c6c749e) [recommends](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) you use data-only containers. You can reuse already available data-only containers:

  `$ docker run --volume /data:/data --name mydata dylanlindgren/docker-laravel-data`
- If you want this change to be permanent, you need to add last command inside startup config file /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh

  `sleep 10 && sudo mount -t vboxsf -o "defaults,uid=33,gid=33,rw" mydata /data
  docker start mydata`

Then, you will have your workspace mounted at /data

You can find more documentation about VirtualBox Guest Additions in Boot2Docker [here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions).

Comment: I got this error: mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error
mount: mounting mydata on /data failed: Protocol error

Comment: I add a first step about creating a data-only container. I omitted that step in previous answer.

Comment: Avoid "Protocol error", retrying VBoxManage command. Ensure this command runs without errors.

Comment: @dmoreno: Could you please update this as [boot2docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/) has been deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer for now, as boot2docker has been deprecated.
The same is now achieved with docker-machine.

The answer is described here: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1814

Basically, after mounting the shared folders in the Virtual Box UI, you need to run the following commands in a command prompt:

```
# Note the extra / at the beginning of the path because of msys/MinGW.
docker-machine.exe ssh default 'sudo mkdir --parents //e/Documents/workspace'
docker-machine.exe ssh default 'sudo mount -t vboxsf e/Documents/workspace //e/Documents/workspace'
```

Comment: Under StackOverflow rules, you should not only be providing the steps to complete the task at hand, but explain each line and why you are telling them to do it. Poor answer, 5/10