# docker bad mount driver

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have a use docker on windows and I  use ubuntu image.
I want to use -v function and import my directory from windows on ubuntu.
The error I found is :
bad mount mode specified

```
docker run -v c:/Users/Admin/Desktop:foo -w /foo -it  ubuntu:latest
```

Thanks for any suggestion!
M

Comment: Your Windows directory is NTFS or something similar, I guess -v awaits Linux based filesystem?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586949/how-do-i-map-volume-outside-c-users-to-container-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
docker run -v //c/Users/Admin/Desktop:/foo -w /foo -it ubuntu:latest
```

or

```
docker run -v '/c/Users/Admin/Desktop':'/foo' -w /foo -it ubuntu:latest
```