# Docker container doesn't see files on windows volumes when the volume endpoint isn't on the drive C:

Tags: docker, sass, docker-volume

I want to use a docker image in my work process. For example I want to use larryprice/sass to compile my SASS files to CSS. This image is pretty simple:

```
FROM ruby:2.2 
RUN gem install sass 
WORKDIR /tmp 
ENTRYPOINT ["sass", "--watch", "/src"]
```

I'm using Windows 10, Docker 1.11 and VirtualBox 5.0.16.

My project files placed on work SSD, that mapped to logical drive D - 
D:\Projects\Foo\Bar\web\sass

So, my problem is following: when I attach a volume to the container from drive D: (by $PWD or by full path in MINGW style /D/Projects/Foo/Bar/web/sass) e.g.

```
cd /D/Projects/Foo/Bar/web
docker run --name sass -v $PWD/sass:/src --rm larryprice/sass
```

the container can't see any SASS files:

```
$ docker exec -i -t sass /bin/bash
root@541aabac9ceb:/tmp# ls -al /src/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 May  3 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 50 root root 4096 May  3 13:05 ..
```

But when I mount a volume from system disk (C:) all works fine:

```
$ docker run --name sass -v ~/sass:/src --rm larryprice/sass
[Listen warning]:
  Listen will be polling for changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
>>> New template detected: ../src/test.sass
      write /src/test.css
      write /src/test.css.map
```

How I can mount volumes from any place I need in Windows? Or what I'm doing wrong in my case?

p.s. Add leading slash to the path also not working:

```
docker run --name sass -v //d/Projects/Foo/Bar/web/sass:/src --rm larryprice/sass
```

Comment: The Docker host is the VM running inside Virtualbox so when you mount a volume, it mounts a folder inside that VM not a Windows 10 folder. You have to hack your way to mount a folder from Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30589373/5388620. [Docker for Windows](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/) aims to make volume mounting seamless.

Comment: @ShanShan thanks to the answer. Looks like this is same solution that I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Finally I found an explanation and solution for my own question. This solution will work for both Windows and MacOS X (because both of them uses VirtualBox to make Docker do the things).

The source of the problem consists from two points:

1. By default, VirtualBox VM have limited access to the host filesystem ([proof](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1814#issuecomment-138983807)). In my case it have access to the users folder on drive C: via VBox shared folder ([screen](http://prntscr.com/b04z44)). Thank to this, I can use volumes mapping like this one: ~/sass:/src (or full path: /c/users/dbykadorov/sass). Unfortunately, this configuration not allows me to use any path outside from /c/users/.

**Solution** for this point: add another shared folder to the VM, pointed on directory I need. I created new share d:/Projects ([screen](http://prntscr.com/b052qs)). Reboot your VM.

I hope here you'll complete your case. But in my case, VirtualBox does not mount new shared folder at system startup. So, I got second problem:

2. VirualBox does not mount additional shared folder, that I just added.

**Additional solution**:

Let's try to mount shared folder manually. Log into VM by any available ways. In console:

```
# Create mount point directory
$ mkdir -p /d/Projects
# Mount shared folder
$ mount -t vboxsf d/Projects /d/Projects
```

Okay, this do the trick! Now I can mount any project's directory (within D:\Projects)!

But... when I'll reboot my VM the mountpoint will disappear =( Now we need to make our mount point more persistent. As described [here](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1814#issuecomment-210090278):

```
# Make a file bootlocal.sh
$ touch /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
# Edit it
$ vi /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh
# Add follovin lines here:
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /d/Projects
mount -t vboxsf d/Projects /d/Projects
# Save the file and reboot VM
```

**Important note**: to make volumes creating more clear it will be good idea to mount shared folder to the same path as on the host. E.g. if we need to create volumes from E:\Foo\Bar\Baz (/e/Foo/Bar/Baz in MINGW style) then we need to add new shared folder for E:\Foo\Bar\Baz and mount it exactly to /e/Foo/Bar/Baz in your Docker VM.

That is All.